# Facebook connect with phonegap 2.1.0 give init error

Tags: jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api, cordova

My code below works fine on the eclipse android simulator. But when I build a android apk using phonegap build at https://build.phonegap.com/ and open it on my incredible 2, I get this popup error "cordova facebook connect plugin fail on init! "

Here is my phone gap app. you can download it. https://build.phonegap.com/apps/211586/share

My code in the git repositiry is here

https://bitbucket.org/sunmeet/phonegab2.0_fbapi

This code is based on hackbook example on https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect/tree/master/example/HackBook at davejohnson / phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect and run with phonegap 2.1.0. I followed all the steps in tutorial.

How can I fix it.

Comment: Does the Hackbook example work on your device?

Comment: No it doesn't. it only works on the adb simulator. but when i create a apk through phonegap build it does not